# show / hide table rows after clicking on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove all table rows after the user had clicked the checkbox, except the table row with the checkbox itself, and to show the table rows back when unchecked the checkbox again. My code is working for removing only but I need to show the table again after unchecking it.

```
function Showhidefunc(btndel) {
  if (typeof(btndel) == "object") {
    $('table tr td:first-child :checkbox:not(:checked)').closest('tr').remove();
  } else {
      return false;
  }
}

<thead>
<tr>
   <th>Select</th>
   <th>Month</th>
   <th>Username</th>
   <th>Deduction</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" onChange="Showhidefunc(this);"></td>
  <td><?php echo $Name_row ['Month'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $Name_row ['Username'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $Name_row ['Total_Deduction'];?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Thanks Guys :)

Comment: Don't `.remove()`  the rows - once you remove them, they're gone.  Use `.hide()` then `.show()`

Comment: You could use jQuery's [toggle()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp).

Comment: that helped me too , thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `.remove()` on the rows as this deletes them; once you remove them, they're gone and you can't get them back.

Use `.hide()` then `.show()`

```
function Showhidefunc(chkbox) {
    if ($(chkbox).is(":checked"))
        $('table tr td:first-child :checkbox:not(:checked)').closest('tr').hide();
    } else {
        $('table tr td:first-child :checkbox:not(:checked)').closest('tr').show();
    }
  }
```

UPDATED: Updated code to match html and better if/else

Version with [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display):

```
function Showhidefunc(chkbox) {
    $('table tr td:first-child :checkbox:not(:checked)').closest('tr').toggle(!$(chkbox).is(":checked"));
  }
```

As an aside, there's other ways to do this, such as using `.map()`

Answer (score 0):

`function Showhidefunc(btndel) {
  if (typeof(btndel) == "object") {
  $('table tr td:first-child :checkbox:not(:checked)').closest('tr').remove();
  } else 
     {
      return false;
     }
  }`

that .remove should be `.hide()`

in the else you want to do the same but use `.show()` instead